# Should I unit-test with data that should not be passed in a function (invalid input)?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I am trying to use TDD for my coding practice. I would like to ask should I test with a data that should not happen in a function BUT this data may possibly break your program.

Here is one of a easy example to illustrate to what I ask :

a ROBOT function that has a one INT parameter. In this function I know that the valid range would only be 0-100. If -1, 101 is used, the function will be break.

```
function ROBOT (int num){
...
...
...
return result;
}
```

So I decided some automated test cases for this function...

```
1. function ROBOT with input argument 0
2. function ROBOT with input argument 1
3. function ROBOT with input argument 10
4. function ROBOT with input argument 100
```

But should I write test cases with input argument -1 or 101 for this ROBOT function IF I would guard that in my other function that call function ROBOT???

```
5. function ROBOT with input argument -1
6. function ROBOT with input argument 101
```

I don't know if it is necessary cause I think it is redundancy to test -1 and 101. And If it is really necessary to cover all the cases, I have to write more code to guard -1 and 101.

So in Common practice of TDD, will you write test case on -1 and 101 as well???

Comment: Not so much a TDD common practice, but there are specific functional testing techniques defined for dealing with ranges and boundaries like the case in your example. See my answer for details.

Comment: Does your language have accessibility modifiers? If `ROBOT()` is private you shouldn't be testing it, you should only test public functions/methods.

Comment: I've made a slight change to the title since the answer to this question will be useful to all testing methodologies, not just TDD. Please rollback if it's not accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, if it can break, then you should test it. Also validate data at the earliest point possible.

The answer depends on whether you control the inputs passed to Robot. If Robot is an internal class (C#) ; values only flow in from RobotClientX which is a public type. Then I'd put the guard checks in RobotClientX, write tests for it. I'd not write tests for Robot, because invalid values cannot materialize in-between.
e.g. if I put my validations in the GUI such that all invalid values are filtered off at the source, then I don't check for invalid values in all classes below the GUI (Unless I've also exposed a public API which bypasses the GUI).

On the other hand, if Robot is publicly visible i.e. Anyone can call Robot with any value that they please, then I need tests that document it's behavior given specific kinds of input.. invalid being one of them. e.g. if you pass an out-of-range value, it'd throw an ArgumentException.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you should test those invalid inputs. BUT, if your language has accessibility modifiers and `ROBOT()` is private you shouldn't be testing it; you should only test public functions/methods.

---

The functional testing technique is called **Boundary Value Analysis**.

If your range is 0-100, your boundary values are 0 and 100. You should test, *at least*:

- below the boundary value
- the boundary value
- above the boundary value

In this case:

> -1,0,1,
>   99,100,101

You assume everything below -1 to -infinity behaves the same, everything between 1-99 behaves the same and everything above 101 behaves the same. This is called **Equivalence Partitioning**. The ranges outside and between the boundary values are called partitions and you assume that they will have equivalent behaviour.

You should always consider using -1 as a test case to make sure nothing funny happens with negative numbers and a text string if the parameter is not strongly typed.

Comment: +1 for BVA mentioning. :) Also, you should check commonly used "special values", even if they are not part of the BVs. Examples are of course 0 and -1. Also, some (really old) legacy systems made use of 999. You should also add the maximum and minimum values for the data type in use (such as int.MaxValue, in .NET).

Answer (score 8):

If the expected outcome is that an exception is thrown with invalid input values, then a test that the exceptions get properly thrown would be appropriate.

Edit:

As I noted in my comment below, if these cases will break your application, you should throw an exception.  If it really is logically impossible for these cases to occur, then I would say no, you don't need to throw an exception, and you don't need test cases to cover it.

Note that if your system is well componentized, and this function is one component, the fact that it is logically impossible *now* doesn't mean it will always be logically impossible.  It may be used differently down the road.

Comment: I have corrected, what about if it is only break the code and would not raise exception? (i have amended my question) :p

Comment: If it breaks the application, it *should* throw an exception!

Answer (score 6):

You said your method will raise an exception if the argument is not valid.

So, yes you should, because you should test that the exception gets raised.

Comment: Well, what about if not? It will only break the program?

Comment: this sort of testing is a bit of an artform.  I would test it, just because it is easy to do and it makes your tests more complete.  If the behavior is undefined for invalid inputs, then you can make the argument for not testing.

Comment: @hvgotcodes, this sort of testing has been made scientific rather than artful thankfully. There's 2 defined techniques to get the minimum test cases. +1 for making it clear that you can't test behaviour that's not defined, but I wouldn't make the argument for not testing the invalid inputs, this behaviour should be defined and show an incomplete spec if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

If other code guards against calling that method incorrectly, and no one else will be writing code to call that method, then I don't see a reason to test with invalid values.  To me, it would seem a waste of time.

Comment: Since you can't guarantee that someone won't call `ROBOT()` incorrectly and there's defined, expected behaviour for invalid inputs, then it should be tested. Unless it's private.

Answer (score 2):

The *programming by contract* style of design and implementation draws attention to the fact that a single function (method) should be responsible for only some things, not for everything. The other functions that it calls (delegates to) and which call it also have responsibilities. This partition of responsibilities is at the heart of dividing the task of programming into smaller tasks that can be performed separately. The *contract* part of programming by contract is that the specification of a function says what a function must do **if and only if** the caller of the function fulfills the responsibilities placed on the caller by that specification. The requirement that the input integer is within the range [0,100] is that kind of requirement.

Now, unit tests should not test implementation details. They should test that the function conforms to its specification.  This enables the implementation to change without the tests breaking. It makes refactoring possible.

Combining those two ideas, how can we write a test for a function that is given some particular *invalid* input? We should check that the function behaves *according to the specification*. But the specification does not say what the function must do in this case. So we can not write any checks of the program state after the invalid function call; the behaviour is *undefined*. So we can not write such a test at all.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is that, no, you don't want exceptions, you don't want to have to have `ROBOT()` check for out of range input.  The clients should be so well behaved that they don't pass garbage values in.

You might want to document this - Just say that clients must be careful about the values they pass in.

Besides where are you going to get invalid values from?  Well, user input or by converting strings to numbers.  But in those cases it should be the conversion routines that perform the checks and give feedback about whether the values are valid or not.  The values should be guaranteed to be valid long before they get anywhere near `ROBOT()`!