# Should I have failing tests?

Tags: unit-testing

Please note: I'm not asking for your opinion. I'm asking about conventions.

I was just wondering whether I should have both passing and failing tests with appropriate method names such as, `Should_Fail_When_UsageQuantityIsNegative()` , `Should_Fail_When_UsageQuantityMoreThan50()` , `Should_Pass_When_UsageQuantityIs50()`.

Or instead, should I code them to pass and keep all the tests in Passed condition?

Comment: All tests should pass. If something is supposed to fail, your test should test for failure (and hence, pass).

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338334/should-i-unit-test-with-data-that-should-not-be-passed-in-a-function-invalid-in

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you create unit tests, they should all pass. That doesn't mean that you shouldn't test the "failing" cases. It just means that the test should pass when it "fails."

This way, you don't have to go through your (preferably) large number of tests and manually check that the correct ones passed and failed. This pretty much defeats the purpose of automation.

As Mark Rotteveel points out in the comments, just testing that something failed isn't always enough. Make sure that the failure is the *correct* failure. For example, if you are using error codes and `error_code` being equal to `0` indicates a success and you want to make sure that there is a failure, don't test that `error_code != 0`; instead, test for example that `error_code == 19` or whatever the *correct* failing error code is.

**Edit**

There is one additional point that I would like to add.  While the final version of your code that you deploy should not have failing tests, the best way to make sure that you are writing correct code is to write your tests *before* you write the rest of the code. Before making any change to your source code, write a unit test (or ideally, a few unit tests) that should fail (or fail to compile) now, but pass after your change has been made. That's a good way to make sure that the *tests* that you write are testing the correct thing. So, to summarize, your final product should not have failing unit tests; however, the software development process *should* include periods where you have written unit tests that do not yet pass.

Comment: Thanks heaps! This explains it well.

Comment: Also make sure to test that it fails in the right way.

Answer (score 5):

You should not have failing tests unless your program is acting in a way that it is not meant to.

If the intended behavior of your program is for something to fail, and it fails, that should trigger the test to pass.

If the program passes in a place where it should be failing, the test for that portion of code should fail.

In summary, a program is not working properly unless all tests are passing.

Comment: Thanks heaps!Sorry I could only mark one answer as the correct one hence up voted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should never have failing tests, as others have pointed out, this defeats the purpose of automation.  What you might want are tests that verifies your code works as expected when inputs are incorrect.  Looking at your examples `Should_Fail_When_UsageQuantityIsNegative()` is a test that should *pass*, but the assertions you make depend on what *fail* means.  For example, if your code should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when usage quantity is negative then you might have a test like this:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void Should_Fail_When_UsageQuantityIsNegative() {
    // code to set usage quantity to a negative value
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps!Sorry I could only mark one answer as the correct one hence up voted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different ways to interpret the question if tests should fail.

A test like `Should_Fail_When_UsageQuantityMoreThan50()` should instead be a passing test which checks the appropriate error is thrown.  `Throws_Exception_When_UsageQuantityMoreThan50()` or the like.  Many test suites have special facilities for testing exceptions: [JUnit's expected parameter](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Exception-testing) and Perl modules such as [Test::Exception](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Exception) and can even [test for warnings](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Warn).

Tests should fail during the course of development, it means they're doing their job.  You should be suspicious of a test suite which never fails, it probably has bad coverage.  The failing tests will catch changes to public behavior, bugs, and other mistakes by the developer or the tests or the code.  But when committed and pushed, the tests should be returned to passing.

Finally, there are legitimate cases where you have a known bug or missing feature which cannot at this time be fixed or implemented.  Sometimes bugs are incidentally fixed, so it's good to write a test for it.  When it passes, you know the bug has been fixed, and you want a notice when it starts passing.  Different testing systems allow you to write tests which are expected to fail, and will only be visible if they pass.  In Perl this is the [TODO or expected failure](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More#Diagnostics).  POSIX has a number of results such as [UNRESOLVED, UNSUPPORTED and UNTESTED](http://iwl.com/white-papers/snmp-testing/posix-standard-result-code) to cover this case.

Comment: Wow! Such an informative answer. Thanks heaps! I appreciate it and learnt a lot.  I already have marked the first person who answered as the correct answer hence will up vote your answer.